# Absolute file path in PHP for linking assets

Tags: php

I have been setting up a simple framework for myself to use for projects with PHP.

My basic folder structure is currently as follows from the root:

- root folder

  - package.json
  - gruntfile.js
  - node_modules
  - src

    - index.php
    - pages

      - about.php
      - contact.php
    - partials

      - header.php
      - footer.php
    - js
    - css

Because I'm storing all of my pages in their own directory but the index.php just outside of the pages directory, what I am essentially looking for is a way to get the absolute path to the index.php that I can then store in a variable and call for any links such as the stylesheet or javascripts within the site.

So my question basically is just how to do that. I am currently using MAMP as my localhost environment, feel free to ask me about any other information regarding my question that I might have missed.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried `__FILE__` ?

Comment: Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php. I guess, `__FILE__` should do the trick

Comment: And if you want to get folder where your index file resides, then you can use `dirname(__FILE__)`. And I also advise you to use `realpath`. That is all you need.

Comment: @Jacobian `__DIR__` is the equivalent of `dirname(__FILE__)`, it's been there since 5.3. Will give the directory of the current file.

Comment: @Ollie. That is right. Documentation says, that the are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, your index.php would be also where you set your Apache DocumentRoot?

If I understood correctly, you can use PHP's $_SERVER variable and the one you would be interest in is $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]

On the other hand, you mentioned you wanted to use this variable for CSS and Javascript files? From a client side it would be impossible to use an absolute file path but you would rather need a relative path (because the client aka browser, have no visibility on your web server's file system).

If you are serious about this framework, I would also suggest looking into design patterns such as [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). And also consider implementing a [FrontController](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) to dispatch all your requests. This would give you more control on paths and how you parse your files.

Comment: I've looked into MVC with things such as Angular, however I am still a novice in that area. What I'm really looking for is just a basic PHP routing system for my pages.

Comment: @kkslider Did you try my suggestion? it should help you get started. Remember that server side and client sides are two different perspectives and you cannot use the exact same variables for both.